# Creating multiple implementations of a gherkin feature file

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

Suppose I have a feature file listing a number of scenarios (the actual contents of the feature file are irrelevant).

I would like to reuse the same feature file and provide a number of implementations:

- Unit test suite implementation.

  - This implementation would mock away external aspects such as the DB/repositories.
  - This implementation would be fast to run.
- Acceptance integration test suite implementation.

  - This would be run in a staging environment and would not mock anything (except perhaps external services where appropriate).
  - This implementation would be slow to run (because it requires all infrastructure to be up and running).

I have tried:

- Placing the feature files in their own sub-project in a mono-repo.
- Have other sub-projects depend on the feature files.
- Implementing the tests.

Although this works I can no longer jump from the feature file to the step definitions (because they are in a different module) in IntelliJ (which lessens the appeal).

Has anyone else had any experience of doing something similar? Or would you recommend against doing this?

Answer (score 1):

We have done something similar.

What you could do is specify 2 different runners, `RunCucumberTest` and `RunCucumberIT`, where the first would be used to run unit tests and should point to the step definitions for the unit tests and the second would be used to run integration tests and should point to the step definitions for the integration tests. In the `@CucumberOptions` you can specify which step definitions (`glue`) the runner should use; just make sure to separate the "unit test" step definitions and the "integration test" step definitions in separate files/directories.

If there are any step definitions that *don't* depend on the distinction between unit and integration test, those could be in a "shared" step definitions file/directory, and called by both runners.

Files ending in *Test should be picked up in unit testing phase by Surefire.
Files ending in *IT should be picked up in unit testing phase by Failsafe.

Hope this helps.